# Java TreeMap equivalent in C#?

Tags: c#, java, treemap, equivalent

Most places I've consulted say to use SortedList, but the problem is that the program I'm porting actually uses duplicate keys (differentiated by order), which is permissible with TreeMap, but not SortedList.

Any advice?

Answer (score 22):

Does [SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class help?

Comment: The SortedDictionary will not work because it throws ArgumentException on duplicate keys.  As the OP said, duplicate keys will be present.

Comment: Just use [`SortedDictionary<of TKey, of TValue>.Item[TKey]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2.item?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_SortedDictionary_2_Item__0_) property setter, it replaces value if the key is already in a tree.

Comment: @Leonid Vasilev: That doesn't work either, because then you'll have one item too few in the dictionary, which can cause malfunctions. e.g. happend to me when translating https://github.com/matsim-up/freight-sa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/matsim/up/freight/clustering/containers/ConcaveHull.java to C#

Answer (score 4):

Another great implementation of a Red Black Tree in .NET can be found here: 
http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think C# has one natively.  However there are plenty of examples of Red-Black implementations out there.  Here is one:-

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/redblackcs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Generally use the sorted set

```
public class ItemComparer : IComparer<int[]>
{
    public int Compare(int[] item1, int[] item2)
    {
        if (item1[0] != item2[0]) return item1[0].CompareTo(item2[0]);
        return item1[1].CompareTo(item2[1]);
    }
}
var s = new SortedSet<int[]>(new ItemComparer());
```